# Mongoose + Mlabs + Big amount of data

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mlab

I use mongoose and react to fetch data from a mlab database. The probleme is that the mlab database have a size of 200 MB, it's a collection of more than 400 000 objects. So when i fetch i have JS error (out of memory) or the request is pending during 2 or 3 mins.

I don't know how to improve this request.

I also need to do some data formating and i don't know if it's better on back or front end..

I need your help to find a solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: have you try to paginate the data ?

Comment: No how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
connection.model("myModel").find(query).limit(limit).skip(offset).exec()
```

`query` will be the condition of your search

`limit` will be the number of elements you want to load,

`offset` will be the number of elements you already have loaded and you want to skip

Comment: pagination for the win!

Comment: I need all the data to render some charts, so if i use the pagination technic it's allow me to do that ?

Comment: Yes . Execute a count query to know the amount of records then execute the paginate query until have all the records accumulated in your front end